# XSL PI names starting with XML are reserved

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm parsing XML document to create another XML document.

Document is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="02_tranformation.xsl"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <SRC_TABLE>myTable</SRC_TABLE>
  <SRC_COLUMN>myColumn</SRC_COLUMN>  
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

and 02_tranformation.xsl file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/ROWSET">
    &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
    &lt;!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd"&gt;
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
```

But result is

```
TEMPLATE_ERROR: TRANSFORMATION: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 1
LPX-00209: PI names starting with XML are reserved
```

I've searching for many help sites but I still do not even understang, what does it mean. 
I dont know if it is important but this is running in Apex application, which read table names from database (as select from...), create XML from this result and I'm parsing this result. Problem is, that this code is working in explorer, but not in this application.
Can anyone help me please?
Thanks very much
J.

Comment: If your output method is `text`, why would you need an XML declaration and/or a DOCTYPE declaration? In any case, the result you claim cannot be reproduced using only your code.

Comment: One possible reason for the error is the whitespace before the XML declaration. This will be copied into the result document. The XML parser finding "<?xml" with preceding whitespace might (if it is rather stupid) decide that it can't be an XML declaration (because that can't have preceding whitespace) therefore it must be a processing instruction, and if it's a processing instruction then its name isn't allowed to be "xml".

Comment: The reason is the generated text will be save to file with ending I choose. In real this will be a text but with .xml it will be read and use as xml file.

Comment: The spaces are not the reason of this error. I've deleted all space and error is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to produce a document with the shown declarations is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="powrmart.dtd" />

<xsl:template match="/ROWSET">
    <POWERMART/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the inner application in Apex has any problems with that :-( That's the reason why I'm using text.

Comment: You should find out what kind of output your target application requires - then ask how to produce such output. Using literal text to simulate XML/DOCTYPE declarations should not be necessary.

Comment: I tried it, it worked, but there appear another problem, now I know for sure I cannot generate XML, I have to generate output as TEXT. Problem is:
`<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="powrmart.dtd" />`
dtd file is not in apex application, but I need it here.
Yes, another could be add it after generating this file, but this won´t be one file only, there can be more that houndred of this generated files. That's whay I'll need to generated TEXT output. But thanks for you tip.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean by that. If you're not generating XML, why would you need an XML declaration - that was my question in the first comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

**One way to produce the wanted output -- if you really *must* output this as text**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "'&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM &quot;powrmart.dtd&quot;&gt;'"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on any XML document (ignored/not-used), the result is**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
```

**Do note**: however, that one doesn't need XSLT to write string literals to the output -- do this in C (or whatever traditional PL) application.

One can output the wanted two lines as the prologue of an XML document with proper use of the `<xsl:output>` declaration.

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:output doctype-system="powrmart.dtd" />
```

You don't need to specify the *method*, *version* and *encoding* attributes, because the default values generated for these pseudo-attributes of the XML declaration are exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it, it looks your advice can work. Unfortunatelly I didn't write this inner application so I have no idea what could work here and what couldn't. Thanks, J.

Comment: @MichaelKay explained this in a comment to your question. The text that you generated is later interpreted (by something you invoked) as XML. An XML declaration cannot be preceded by whitespace. In your case it is. Thus the XML Parser doesn't recognize the declaration as such and decides it is an ordinary processing-instruction (PI). But the XML standard doesn't recommend element, attribute or PI names to start with the string "xml" in any capitalization. So the error.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work. I think that problem will be in inner application. I'll try to find another solution, without using this application. :-/ But thanks very much for your tip!